# filemtime returns same value before and after modification of file

Tags: php, timestamp, fopen, fwrite, filemtime

Im trying to get the last modified time of a file before and after i write to it using fwrite. But, i get the same values for some reason.

```
<?php
$i = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $i);
echo "<br/>";
$e=fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fwrite($e, "well well well");
$j = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $j);

?>
```

Now i modify 'log.txt' with a text editor about a minute before i run this script. So i should be getting about 40-60 seconds of time difference. If someone could point out what is happening here, that'd be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. filemtime has been reporting the same timestamp for a file I have been editing. The timestamp is 4 hours ago when converted to my time zone (https://www.epochconverter.com/). I have tried  clearstatcache(true,FILE);  and without arguments. I have turned off the PHP file content cache. I have appended "?r=RANDOM" to the filename (causes an error because the FILE is local). Windows 10 Home, Apache 2.4, PHP 7, Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of [filemtime](http://php.net/filemtime) states that results of this function are cached. Maybe you can try it with [clearstatcache](http://php.net/clearstatcache):

```
<?php
$i = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $i);
echo "<br/>";
$e=fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fwrite($e, "well well well");
clearstatcache();
$j = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $j);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  :) that worked. Guess i should start paying more attention to the documentation than just usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add fclose after the fwrite:

```
<?php
$i = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $i);
echo "<br/>";
$e=fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fwrite($e, "well well well");
fclose($e);
$j = filemtime('log.txt');
echo gmdate("h:i:s", $j);
?>
```